# local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mysql

```
import DBUtil

def insert_sql(*args, **kw):
    for k, v in kw:
        SQL_INSERT = "insert into nostray(%s) values(%s)" % (k, v)
    return SQL_INSERT
    sql = insert_sql("userid", "02")
    DBUtil.excute(sql)
```

I wrote a util to connect db, and execute sql, an error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>  
  sql = insert_sql("userid", "02"). 
  File "test.py", line 6, in insert_sql.  
  return SQL_INSERT.  
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'SQL_INSERT' referenced before assignment
```

How to fix this, thx.

Comment: whats in 'kw' i'd guess the for loop is not called because its empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling this function with any keyword arguments; you just pass positional arguments. So, `kw` is empty and the loop is never executed.

I *think* you meant to use `userid` as the key and `02` as the value, so you should do this:

```
sql = insert_sql(userid="02")
```

Note, there are other problems with this code; for example, if you use more than one kwarg, your SQL will only ever contain one of them.